# Windows 2012 R2 Standard trying to backup files that doesn't exists

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-backup

We have a fully patched Windows 2012 R2 standard server that is using windows backup to a usb external drive.  The backup runs but we get a few WID errors that all relate to WSUS.

```
Application Message: (null)
   Component: master
   Logical Path: DC1\MICROSOFT##WID
   Component Result: 800423F4
   Component Message: (null)
       File Spec: C:\Windows\WID\Data\master.mdf Recursive: 0
       File Spec: C:\Windows\WID\Data\mastlog.ldf Recursive: 0
```

We do have WSUS running on this server. When we first installed WSUS the database was housed on this server.  Now the SQL database resides on a different server.  This has been verified by looking at the registry.  The master.mdf file does not exist on this server.  How do we get windows backup to stop looking for the master.mdf file so that our backups can show as successful.

when i look in the registry,

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSWIN8.SQLWID\MSSQLSERVER\Parameters\SQLArg0
```

`REG_SZ - dC:\WindowsWID\Data\master.mdf` does show up.  I've tried to log into SQL using sqlcmd, `sqlcmd -S np:\\dc1\pipe\sql\query` and that did not connect to check on the server.  I also tried using the `-E` switch and also the `-U sa` `-P password` switches and still can't get logged in.

In "Programs and Features" SQL does not show up as something that is installed.

Trying to give all the info you would need to ask some questions.

Figured out the issue:
We have figured it out.  We removed the the MSSQL from the registry using the instruction from the following link.. https://www.javelin-tech.com/blog/2017/08/uninstall-microsoft-sql-server/ and that corrected our backup issues.

Answer (score 0):

This path refers to Windows Internal Database (WID), other roles can use WID (it's not specific to WSUS).

It is possible to uninstall Windows Internal Database by removing the feature:

```
Uninstall-WindowsFeature -Name 'Windows-Internal-Database'
```